# On Update Cascade @ Informix

Tags: sql, informix, cascade

How can I impelement an "On Update Cascade" in an Informix table? On Delete Cascade is working, but obv. there is no option for Updates.

Comment: What do you mean with an 'on update cascade'.  Can you explain the exact goal that you try to achieve?

Comment: On Update Cascade is a feature in other DBMS, that automatically updates all foreign keys, when the corresponding primary key value is changed.

Comment: I know it doesn't solve your question, but with good database design you wouldn't need that system: a PK should be an autoincrement kind of value with no functional value, and therefore, should never be updated.  The only way you can do this kind of thing in Informix, is by using an update trigger.